# Microsoft Graph Upload API: Frequent 504 Gateway Timeout Error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Problem:

I am trying to upload images to one drive and frequently getting error

> 504 Gateway Timeout (Unknown error ).

API used:

```
PUT
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/drive/items/{rootFolderId}/{folderPath}/{fileName}:/content
```

Response:

```
504 Gateway Timeout
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "9709847a-36d4-42f2-90dd-4c37094caead",
            "date": "2018-05-16T12:18:37"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you upload the images to the drive using the Web UI? then see them in the Do other operations work on files in this folder? can you get the files back in that folder? e.g.
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{folder-id}/children